# Solaris 11_3 Installation on LDom via "telnet localhost 5000"

Tags: system-installation, solaris

I am new to the Unix section here in my company and now I got the task to install Solaris 11 on a new LDom. Reading the documentation, I was able to create and configure the primary domain and I was able to create a guest domain with vCPUs, memory, diskspace etc. I created a local ISO file from the *Solaris 11_3 installation DVD* and added it to the guest domain.

Now, when I connect to the LDom and execute "boot sol11_3_install" the installation interface comes up. But, unfortunately, I cannot complete the installation because my keys are not working properly. **F2** , **ESC-2** or other keys are not working. Cursor Keys are also not working.

So, how do I proceed through the installation when my keyboard is not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly. That is a bug of the LDOMS software and/or firmware.
Try to update the LDOMS software and on the physical machine and try again to connected and also update the firmware.